# Removing a single value from a multiValue field in solr 4.5

Tags: python, solr, solr4

I am new in solr.solr query i am getting data like

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1449483445811",
      "wt": "json",
      "fq": "id:0553573403"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "0553573403",
        "cat": [
          "book",
          "book1"
        ],
        "name": "Cyberpunk",
        "price": 7.99,
        "price_c": "7.99,USD",
        "inStock": true,
        "author": "George R.R. Martin",
        "author_s": "George R.R. Martin",
        "series_t": "A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i": 1,
        "genre_s": "fantasy1111",
        "labelRequest_j_12536_matching_profile": "1",
        "_version_": 1519893543721631700
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

schema.xml is

```
   <field name="cat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

then i am trying to delete data with postman , post method and content type json with this

```
url-http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/json?commit=true
    {
      "id"       : "0553573403",
      "cat"      : {"remove":"book1"}
     }
```

then response

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":616}}
```

But it is not removing data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `id` is your `uniqueKey` field.

The `remove` update option is not available until Solr 4.9, see
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3862

I guess you have to overwrite the field value list as a whole like this:

```
{
    "id"       : "0553573403",
    "cat"      : {"set":["book1"]}
}
```

Comment: Thanx  Simon  but is not a proper way .here first get data  then remove that text and again set data in solr